# django unable to connect mysql server on aws

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-web-services

my django version is 2.0.1, i would like to connect with mysql. Database which is located on a amzon ec2

[I get this error when I'm running the Django server :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cziXt.png)

this is my settings.py 
DATABASES = {

```
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'graph',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'hostname',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you made sure the name, user, password, etc. are all correct? Seems obvious, but that might be it?

Comment: Check that your firewall/aws security groups allow access from the application server to the database server.

Comment: try to connect using `mysql -h hostname -u graph -p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check few things in your infra as well as MySQL configuration.

- Check your security group & NACL that mysql port is open on your mysql ec2 server.
- Did you allow remote connection in MySQL? if not then use below query to allow remote connection from publicly.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Feel free to comment if both points are configured properly.